# How to Customized / Search in Jmeter log

Tags: logging, groovy, jmeter

Hey All I have a question about Jmeter log.
I usually use consul, and I want to try using log
log.info("My message");

when the test run I press the yellow triangle in the up right section.
and the log section appeared,
the problem is it full with data that I do not need, 
so:
1. I take all the log 
2. move it to notepad++
3. search the data I want ("my message")

it takes a lot of time' can someone suggest a better way to search in the log itself? or just see exception and my printing?
regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to search (as of JMeter 3.3) in console output.

The output reflect the content of bin/jmeter.log. So you can directly open this file with any editor and do the search there.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the amount of data in the log?

Comment: yes, use log level. Set it to warn for example. See bin/log4j2.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just write your message to the **separate** file, in Groovy it would be as simple as:

```
new File('my.log') << 'my message'
```

Getting content of *jmeter.log* file into a [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) would be something like:

```
def jmeterLog = new File('jmeter.log').text
```

References:

- [Groovy JDK Enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) - check out **Writing to and reading from files** chapter

Comment: Hey dimity, this still not solved the issue since it is just writing from a file to the log, I want somehow to reduce the logs level of info, since I got much more data than I need, can you advise if I can control which data to display in info level of logs?